# Bitbucket Pipelines upload to Artifactory does not get correct build name

Tags: gradle, artifactory, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using BitBucket pipelines to upload artifacts to Artifactory using gradle and have everything working as expected except for the name being given to the artifact when it is uploaded to artifactory:

1. Building the artifact in Pipelines via:

   `bash ./gradlew build artifactoryPublish - 
   Partifactory_user=$ARTIFACTORY_USER - 
   Partifactory_password=$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD`
2. Using this gradle configuration:

   [JS Fiddle with Gradle File](https://jsfiddle.net/ja2f4bmk/1/)
3. And this is the output I get when I run it locally:

   ```
   :artifactoryPublish
   :artifactoryDeploy
   Deploying artifact:
   ```

   Deploying artifact: https://XXXXXX.jfrog.io/XXXXXX/enterpriseconfigserver/com/XXXXXX/framework/enterpriseconfigserver/1.0-SNAPSHOT/enterpriseconfigserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

But when I run it in Pipelines I get this:

Deploying artifact: https://XXXXXX.jfrog.io/XXXXXX/enterpriseconfigserver/com/XXXXXX/framework/build/1.0-SNAPSHOT/build-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: looks like your `artifactId` is `build` instead of `enterpriseconfigserver`

Comment: That worked. Add that as an answer and I'll accept it. I updated the fiddle with the changes: https://jsfiddle.net/ja2f4bmk/2/
It is still naming the TAR and ZIP files as BUILD but I actually do not need those files so working on not generating them. Thanks Yuri.

Comment: regarding the tar and zip file, I assume these file types are being generated by another task that are needed to be configured separately, e.g https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-create-a-tar-file-from-selected-files-from-different-directories/5512/2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `artifactId` is `build` instead of `enterpriseconfigserver`
You can find an example in gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:identity_values_in_the_generated_pom) how to set the `artifactId`